# Calculate total time of each user in single/per day - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
     > Start                    stop                  pinnumber
     > ---------------------------------------------------------
     > 2012-03-14 13:22:17    2012-03-14 15:22:50      2001
     > 2012-03-14 18:11:10    2012-03-14 19:10:10      2001
     > 2012-03-15 07:20:10    2012-03-15 13:20:50      2001
     >**2012-03-16 19:21:55       2012-03-17 02:55:22  2001** //on 16(19:21:55
                                                                     to 23:59:59) and     
                                                                 //on 17(00 to 02:55:22) 
     > 2012-03-17 14:15:05    2012-03-17 17:44:50      2001
     > 2012-03-18 19:11:10    2012-03-18 19:10:10      2002
     > 2012-03-18 10:20:10    2012-03-18 13:20:50      2003
     > 2012-03-18 11:20:10    2012-03-18 15:11:50      2001
```

Question:

How can I calculate total time of each user of per day ('start', 'stop') per day? Please see the above highlighted point. Suppose, If user 'start' today and stop it tomorrow then today hour are different and tomorrow hour are different?

right now i am using following query:-

> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`stop` ,`start` ) ) ) ) AS time1, clock. * FROM table_name WHERE `pin_number` = '2001' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( `start` , '%W %M %Y' )

from above query i am getting per day records but when start date and stop date is different. it calculate total time not single day time but i need per day time.

Comment: So is what you're doing working? If not, what's going wrong? Do you get an error? Or what results are you expecting/getting?

Comment: the problem is he is grouping by the start day so it might credit over 48 hours to a single day if start is on monday and stop is sometime wednesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally got there.  You first need to get a set of days, which I obtain through a subquery that takes a `UNION` of the start and stop times (you could filter this for your `pinnumber` if desired in order to reduce the size of the `JOIN`).

One then joins each such date with those `(start,stop)` pairs that encompass that date (i.e. either start during the day, or the start of the day is between the start and stop time).

Finally, one groups by day and takes the sum of the amount of time between the start and end times, cutting off at the day start and end as appropriate (the magic `86400` is the number of seconds in a day = 24*60*60).  Sadly this won't play nice with daylight savings, leap seconds, etc...

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(unixday, '%d/%m/%Y'), SUM(
    LEAST(   unixday+86400, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Stop ))
  - GREATEST(unixday      , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Start))
) AS Seconds
FROM table_name JOIN (

  SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(Start)) AS unixday FROM table_name
UNION 
  SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(Stop )) AS unixday FROM table_name

) AS days ON (
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Start) BETWEEN unixday AND unixday+86400
  OR (unixday BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Start) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Stop))
)
WHERE pinnumber = 2001
GROUP BY unixday;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2538d/23).